# Tool allowing moving windows beneath modal (blocking) window

Tags: windows, user-interface

Maybe you know the following situation well (description is below the image):

[image]

Windows application is asking you about some settings in so-called [**modal window**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) which appears on top and blocks access to all other windows of the application until it is closed, which can have [many drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window#Criticism). If you click them, you will see the modal window flashing, drawing your attention back to it. Sometimes the windows stack (on image `1`->`2`->`3`) and in window `3` you find that file path was visible in window `1`. But you cannot move window `2` to uncover window `1` so you must close window `3`, then move window `2` and reopen window `3` again. I would like if I could move windows `1` and `2` if window `3` is open as modal (while windows `1` and `2` can be also modal in some cases).

Is there a tool to modify Windows behavior allowing you to move windows underneath current modal window?